# How to render blob image in vue.js stored in database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vue.js, blob, sequelize.js

I am using Vue.js in the front-end. I have Node.js, Express, PostgreSQL (with [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) ) on the backend.

I am storing an item in the database that includes  a thumbnail image.

**Database Model**

```
const Item = sequelize.define('item', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false,
    },

    image: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB('long'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
```

Database-wise, the image is being stored as a Blob and I think this is fine (and yes, I am aware that it's not best-practice to put images in a database).

I observe in the browser that the object that I am accessing in my Vue template with `this.item.image` is an Object of the type `Buffer`.

[image: Console shows this is an Object with type Buffer]

**Adding to Database**

I add the item to the database in the browser with this in my  vue template:

```
     <label for="image" class="itemCreate__field itemCreate__field--image">
       <span class="itemCreate__fieldLabel">Image</span>
       <input id="file"  type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onFileChange"/>
        <img v-if="itemPreviewImage" :src="itemPreviewImage" />
     </label>
```

And that HTML relies on these methods:

```
     onFileChange(evt) {
        const files = evt.target.files || evt.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length) return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);

    },
    createImage(file) {
        const image = new Image();
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = evt => {
            this.itemPreviewImage = evt.target.result;
            this.item.image = evt.target.result;
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    },
```

I have this in the vue template that renders the image:

```
        <div v-if="item.image">
            <img :src="imgUrl" alt="Picture of item"/>
        </div>
```

**Rendering from Database**

I have tried the following approaches, which do not work:

`createObjectUrl` borrowed from [here](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/wiki/Display-an-image-stored-in-a-BLOB-in-a-browser):

```
    imgUrl(){
      const objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(this.item.image.data));

      return objUrl;
    }
```

Creating a base64 string borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140223/how-to-display-an-image-in-react-from-postgresql):

```
    imgUrl(){
        const intArray = new Uint8Array(this.item.image.data);
        const reducedArray = intArray.reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '');

        const base64String = `data:image/png;base64, ${btoa(reducedArray)}`;


        return base64String;
    }
```

Creating a new `Uint8Array` and then getting an objectUrl (borrowed [here](https://gist.github.com/candycode/f18ae1767b2b0aba568e)):

```
imgUrl(){
  const arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(this.item.image);
  const blob  = new Blob([arrayBuffer], {type: "image/png"});

  return window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

}
```

In all cases (including some attempts with FileReader), I get broken images. I don't get errors in the console, though.

I *think* the issue is that I am not submitting correct data to the database.

I am sending an Ajax request that has the File attached as a property, and I should probably convert it to ¿something else?

Comment: I was having basically this exact same issue, in the middle of posting another question when I found this one, I got past it by uploading the base64 string as a `dataType.TEXT`.  This does not feel like the right solution but for the small project I'm building not a big deal.   Here is a repo with a small working example:  [postgres pic](https://github.com/ed42311/postgres-pic-vue).  `master`  has datatype blob attempted, `text-solution` has the text solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure you're getting a valid `base64` string: https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Then try defining a getter to the `Item` model

```
const Item = sequelize.define('item', {
    ...
    image: {
        type: Sequelize.BLOB('long'),
        allowNull: true,
        get () { // define a getter
            const data = this.getDataValue('image')
            return data ? data.toString('base64') : ''
        },
        set(val) {
          this.setDataValue('image', val);
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

#### Computed property

```
imgURL () {
    return this.item.image
        ? 'data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,' + this.item.image 
        : '' // some default image

}
```

Comment: I tried that exact code and ended up with `<img src="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64[object Object]" alt="Picture of item">` 

I think I need to somehow stringify that object in my computed prop

Comment: Upon Closer review, it looks like the base64 apparently isn't valid. So that means there's a problem with how I'm _submitting_ the image to the database

Comment: You should be passing a Buffer to `item.image` before saving it. Add the code to the question so we can check if that's ok. Also, try setting `long` length to `Sequelize.BLOB('long')`

Comment: I've updated the question to include how I'm adding the file. I also modified my model. 

How can I be sure that I'm passing a buffer? in my `createImage` method in my "add" template, it doesn't work even if I try `this.item.template = file` ...  This is my ignorance as I'm not sure I know when a file becomes a buffer and vice versa

Comment: As a side note I tried these things:
  passed ArrayBuffer, converted with FileReader   /   passed base64 string (w and wo substr)  / passed just the file from `new FileReader()`  /   passed the file from `fs-web` fileRead...  a few of these options could be decoded with `atob` but the string was not valid after decoding.